# Powershell error if the hardware is not there

Tags: powershell, usb, barcode-scanner

I am trying to get a powershell script to see if I have a USB scanner connected.

If it is there, it is working like I need if it is not it will error.

I would like to be able to have it just end or let me know there is no scanner attached.

The line that offends when it is not there is:

```sh
$USBscanner = wmic path CIM_LogicalDevice where "DeviceID like 'USB\\VID_0C2E%' and DeviceID like 'USB\\%PID_0B01%' and Description like 'USB Composite Device%'" get /value
```

Comment: As an aside: `wmic.exe` is officially deprecated, as evidenced by `wmic /?` printing `WMIC is deprecated` in red, as the first (nonempty) line. Consider using PowerShell's CIM cmdlets, such as [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance), instead, which has the added advantage of returning _objects_ rather than text, for robust subsequent processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check if your variable has any data before continuing with the script, and end it early:

```
if (-not $USBscanner) { Throw 'USB Scanner not found!' }
```

Or you can make all errors terminate your script with a preference:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
```

If you don't want to just terminate the script, you can `try` and `catch` the error from `wmic.exe`:

```
Try {
  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
  wmic path CIM_LogicalDevice WHERE 'DeviceID="MissingDevice"'
}
Catch {
  Write-Warning 'USB Scanner not found'
}
```

As a suggestion, you could be better off using the actual Powershell cmdlets for CIM with the if statement from above. These commands return actual objects that powershell is built to manipulate:

```
# check if USB scanner device is attached:
$USBscanner = Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_LogicalDevice | 
    where {$_.DeviceID -Like 'USB\VID_0C2E*' -and $_.DeviceID -like 'USB\*PID_0B01*'}

if (-not $USBscanner) { Throw 'USB Scanner not found!' }
```

Comment: Thanks Cpt. Whale, that got me to where I wanted to be!

Comment: @Chrisj105, good to hear! please mark it as the answer, or do you have any questions?

Comment: Good advice, except that the `try` / `catch` solution does not work, because `$ErrorActionPreference` has no effect on calls to _external programs_. Check the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) instead. The OP's `wmic` _query string_ can - and should, for efficiency - be passed as-is to `Get-CIMInstance`'s `-Filter` parameter, except that it happens to have a logic flaw (`and` instead of `or`, and fixing that then requires embedded `(...)`).

Comment: @mklement0 ah, thanks! try/catch does work when remoting or in ISE since wmic returns a generic `[NativeCommandError]` exception there (but not in the normal console window, whoops). You are also right on the `-Filter` flag being more efficient, but it should still be `and` (the second string has two wildcards).

Comment: Understood re `and` (I jumped to conclusions). It is unfortunate that the ISE and remoting / background jobs / thread jobs route stderr output through PowerShell's _error stream_, which was never appropriate. Preview versions of v7.2 (which obviously excludes the WinPS-only, obsolescent ISE) now have the `PSNotApplyErrorActionToStderr` experimental feature (on by default in preview versions), which fixes this problem, and this fix will hopefully make it into the next release. Either way, it's ill-advised to rely on the broken behavior, especially given that regular consoles don't exhibit it.